# Data Annotation in NSwag CodeGen Net Core

Tags: c#, typescript, swagger, ef-core-2.2, nswag

When i try to convert the below `enum` property, it doesn't change as expected.

I used the `nswag` to generate the code in `typescript` from my EF core API, the enum based class doesn't convert as expected when using [DisplayName] or [Description] DataAnnotation.

**Property:**

```
[Description("26\"")] TwentySix = 1,
```

**Output:**

```
export enum Sizes {
    TwentySix = 1, 
}
```

**Expectation:**

```
export enum Sizes {
   26"= 1,
}
```

Added the below code in the "ConfigureServices",

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver());
```

Or

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter()));
```

In nswag.json,

Under "codeGenerators" i have the below property,

```
 "enumNameGeneratorType": null,
```

My other service method and classes are working fine. The "`Description`" attribute didn't work, tried "`DisplayName`" too.

What should i change here?

Comment: 1) You would probably need your own custom converter that acknowledges the `DescriptionAttribute` 2) You are duplicating a lot of code in the `ConfigureServices`

Comment: Do you literally mean that it renders the syntactically invalid code above? If so, it's likely to do with the `\"`  In the description. I'm not sure why you would have that character in your description but and swag probably isn't handling it because it's a weird edge case they didn't think of.

Comment: Yeah almost, i was expecting is there anyway that i can bring the expected output.